# Python: Is it possible to create a package out of multiple external libraries?

Tags: python, git, pycharm, package

This issue has been driving me insane for the past few days.

So basically, I'm trying to port over a Pure Python project to a proper PyCharm project. This is to basically improve code quality and project structure.

I wish it was as simple as basically creating a virtualenv to house everything, but it isn't. This project will eventually be developed simultaneously by multiple developers with Git as source control, and the default libraries **will be modified**. I presume this means that the libraries should ideally be tracked by Git in the end. Virtualenv shouldn't help here as far as I know because it's not portable between systems (or at least that's still being tested).

This project will also be, in the future, deployed to a Centos server.

So the only plan I can think of to successfully pull off this would be to simply bring in all of the libraries (which was done using `pip install -t Libraries <ExampleLibrary>`) into a single folder, with a `__init__.py` inside, and use them from other python files as a package within the Pycharm project.

Is this possible / recommended? I tried various methods to reference these libraries, but they all don't work during runtime. Somehow when the files in the library import something else from their own package, an ImportError is raised saying that there's no such module.

Will accept any other suggestions too.

Using Pycharm Community Edition.

EDIT: After having a good night's rest I think the crux of the issue is really just project organization. Before I ported it over to Pycharm the project worked as expected, but this had all of the python files in the root directory, and the libraries in a subfolder of the root, with every project file having the same boilerplate code: 
`import os, sys
absFilePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__));
sys.path.insert(1, absFilePath + "/lib")`

I was hoping that by using Pycharm to help me flesh out the packages, I could avoid having repeated boilerplate code.

Comment: Why will you be modifying your dependencies?  This is usually going to cause you problems... can you just inherit from them and add/modify the functionality you want to change?  If you absolutely HAVE to vendor stuff, look at the requests library which has its own versions of a couple packages in their repo.  (if you are modifying the dependencies, they must be in git from the very beginning!)

Comment: My modifications are just one-liners within some of the library functions, they shouldn't be breaking the structure, I think? Your suggestion to inherit from the libraries was something that I didn't think about, but I don't know how I would make the changes that I want to make if I go in that direction.

And yeah, the original plan before porting the project over to Pycharm was to put those libraries inside the git repo alongside the project folders. But now I just want to have a better project structure, because previously, everything was inside the root folder, which made things messy.

Comment: If your code quality isn't very good you may want to read up on how to fix *that*. Adding an IDE isn't likely to magically fix any of your problems, even one as nice as Pycharm.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you're trying to do something *besides* use your normal `pip install`'d libraries? Cause... don't do that, that's a horrible idea.

Comment: Okay I come from a Java background, so I'm still quite stuck to their naming conventions. At the very least Pycharm enforces PEP-8, which I think is good.

I used pip -t libs install LibraryX, which I guess pip installs the library into a specific folder relative to the shell as opposed to the main Python site-packages library. That's not a good practice?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `pip install -t Libraries ExampleLibrary`

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Not full solution.**

The addition of the template code below forces the file containing the code to be in the same directory as the libs folder.

For Pycharm, all I had to do was mark the libs folder as a source folder. Even with the addition of the template code to the file, the modified libraries still work as expected.

For the Python Shell, this template code is still needed:

```
import os
import sys

absFilePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(1, absFilePath + "/lib")
```